# Django-Compressor does nothing

Tags: python, css, django, minify, django-compressor

I am using django-compressor to compress css files.

I did as it was explained in http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/

I changed my template file as follows:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load compress %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static "crsq/css/zippednewsapp/bootstrap.readable.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "crsq/css/zippednewsapp/zippednewsapp.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "crsq/css/zippednewsapp/typeahead.css" %}"/>
    {% endcompress %}
  </head>

.....
```

I do not see any change what so ever. No error. The files are not compressed. How do I change this?

In my settings file:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If html didn't change, I'd check server restart after the changes.

If not, you can increase logging level and see what does the compressor module print into the logs.

Also,the compressor should run under a user with enough privileges to create files and folders under `COMPRESS_ROOT` (which defaults to `STATIC_ROOT`)

Regards

Comment: COMPRESS_ROOT was the issue. Thanks

Comment: if anyone else runs into this same problem, I was able to resolve it by adding STATIC_ROOT = 'static' to settings.py